# C# BackgroundWorker eats memory on restart

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

I created an empty Form with the following code to test the performance of continuously restarting a background worker;

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            // Do work on Background thread
            bw.DoWork += DoWork_WorkerThread;
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            // Return to UI thread and Restart the worker
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += DoWork_WorkerThreadCompleted;
        }

        private void DoWork_WorkerThread(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            //GC.Collect();
        }

        private void DoWork_WorkerThreadCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Restart the worker.
            // We can verify its the background worker because commenting this out relieves the issue.
            ((BackgroundWorker)sender).RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

You can see that in the task manager everytime the worker is restarted from `DoWork_WorkerThreadCompleted` the memory jumps up.

I noticed that if I toss in a `GC.Collect()` into the worker thread, the problem goes away. Am I restarting the worker incorrectly or is there a way to ensure the background thread gets disposed without calling `GC.Collect()`?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you aware that the GC doesn't call `.Dispose()` on `IDisposable` objects?

Comment: Side note: you should probably assign the RunWorkerCompleted event before calling RunWorkerAsync.

Comment: Also, starting a thread consumes at least 1MB of RAM as it creates a run-time stack among other things.

Comment: Thanks for replies guys and good calls on completed event. Ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only a few use cases where **explicit** calls to GC are required.  Just because memory increases whilst repeating an action doesn’t necessarily mean there is a memory leak. .NET for one only releases memory when it really needs to, like when memory pressure is high.  Calling `GC.Collect` just forces the issue.

Commenting out the worker start doesn't really prove anything.  Though yes you have prevented memory from increasing in this case, you also eliminated the possibility for memory to be released had the worker run to completion and allowed for sufficient time or events for memory to be released again.  **You can never really predict with high certainty when GC will occur.**  Calling `GC.Collect` not withstanding.

You can think of the problem another way.  Imagine allocating an object you know uses a reasonable amount of RAM.

```
void DoSomething()
{
    var ob = new MyObjectRequiringReasonableAmountOfRam();
    // 'ob' goes out of scope and is now a candidate for GC at some time or other
}
```

Now calling this method the object is allocated and goes out of scope and yes memory might increase but it is premature to think there is a memory leak.  Sure commenting out the code removes the symptom of a "leak" but it also removes functionality as is commenting out your worker thread.

Now, if in addition to calling the above method I then call:

```
void DoSomethingSlightlyMoreDrastic()
{
    var ob = new MyObjectRequiringALargerAmountOfRam();
    // 'ob' goes out of scope and is now a candidate for GC at some time or other
}
```

....NET seeing that this allocation requires more memory and taking into account all the other factors on your system such as how much memory your process has allocated; memory from all other processes; RAM in your computer and the rules of how GC works, **it is entirely possible that your first object gets GC'd at this point.**

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. In this scenario at some point shouldn't I see the garbage collector kick in and either level out or lower the memory usuage? It appears that on this example the increase is constant

Comment: @clamchoda You are welcome.  Maybe it is kicking in and you are not aware?  Run it in the debugger and ensure the **Diagnostic Tools** window is open.  GC events are normally shown in yellow.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/02/15/analyze-cpu-memory-while-debugging/